# cvs2git blob and dump file

Tags: git, cvs

I am trying to import a cvs project in git using `cvs2git`.

I am using following command

```
cvs2git --username=reza -v --blobfile=./blob.txt  --dumpfile=./dump.txt ./localCVSTree/repo
```

I see the blob file getting created and I do not see the dump file getting created.

Why does that happen? Is that an error?

Any experience with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason cvs2git must not have run to completion.  It is impossible to tell why without more information.

Comment: there was a encoding issue and the command line fixed that, so yes I was getting an error. Now all is working.